# Return CSV file with Poco C++ library's HTTPRequestHandler

Tags: c++, http, poco-libraries

I have a server application using Poco C++ library to handle HTTP requests. I cannot really find much documentation or examples on how to return a CSV file from the HTTP server. Has anyone done this?

In essence this is what I have so far, but I do not understand how to return the text as a CSV file.

```
/// Return a CSV document.
class GetCSVFileHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:
    GetCSVFileHandler()
    {          
    }

    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {        
        std::string result = "1,2,3\n a,b,c\n";

        // ??????????????????????????????????????????????????
        // how to return a CSV file here?
        // ??????????????????????????????????????????????????
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();
        ostr << result;
    }   
};
```

Comment: Can you give some details: what is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Return a CSV document.
class GetCSVFileHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:

    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {

        response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
        response.setContentType("text/csv");

        std::string result = "1,2,3\n a,b,c\n";
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();
        ostr << result;
    }   
};
```